# How to download a pdf file from Dropbox API response

Tags: coldfusion, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am getting a response from Coldbox API in ColdFusion but I am unable to convert this response to PDF in Coldfusion. I have attached an image of the response below.
[image]
Here is my code:

```
<cfhttp result="get" method="POST"  url="https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download" getAsBinary="yes"   >
   <cfhttpparam type="header"name="Authorization"  value="#token#">
   <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Dropbox-API-Arg" value="#serializeJSON(pathData)#">
</cfhttp>  
       
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="inline; filename=test.pdf" />  
<cfheader name="content-transfer-encoding" value="binary" /> 
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" variable="#get.Filecontent#" reset="true" />
```

I want to Hit API and download the file in next tab.
Let me know If anyone can help me to fix that issue.
Thanks.

Comment: See this link... Looks like being the same problem as yours https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion-discussions/output-binary-data-to-browser-as-file/m-p/731569

Comment: @AndreasRu I have tried this already but It is not working for me.

Comment: It may be the data or an unexpected response by dropbox. What do you get if you dump the 'get' variable with <cfdump var="#get#">? Any hints in comparision with a working 'pdf' request?

Comment: Hi @AndreasRu I added a shot about which has the response of "get".

Comment: @BasitAli - That doesn't look like a dump of "get". A dump of the full http response should show a lot more values, such as headers, and binary fileContent is displayed differently than what's in your screen shot.  Example https://trycf.com/gist/29113108ada26f7d4515b4c43f69003c/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: @basit ali I can't see any shot added of your first request. Please mask/remove any sensible data in case you add it as a screenshot.